# Day of Defeat Server runs but nobody can join

Tags: steam, server-administration, day-of-defeat

> Preface: I was not sure if I should ask here or on serverfault but I think it is more a game issue than a server issue itself...

I have a small dedicated server rented which runs Counterstrike (1.6, not Source!) since yesterday. I used the SteamCMD tool to install everything I need and it nearly worked out of the box. (Used the [steamcmd documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD))

Now I try to do the same for Day of Defeat (again, not Source) and after some struggling the server finally boots fine.

```
# ./hlds_run -console -game dod +maxplayers 8 -port 27016
Auto-restarting the server on crash

Console initialized.
Using breakpad crash handler
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 30
Forcing breakpad minidump interfaces to load
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Protocol version 48
Exe version 1.1.2.7/Stdio (dod)
Exe build: 17:45:07 Apr 25 2013 (6027)
STEAM Auth Server
Server IP address 78.47.102.222:27016
couldn't exec listip.cfg
couldn't exec banned.cfg
```

The real problem is that I can't connect to my own server! I used the IP and the hostname (always with the port) and I tried to search ingame for game servers on that IP (you can do that when adding an IP/Address to favorits) but only my CS server is displayed.

I also shut down my CS instance and used the default port, still the same issue. The server always starts but I can't connect...

One thing I saw which made me wonder: the server.cfg mentions dod v1.2 but with the latest update it should be dod v1.3. Is there any way I can verify the dod version of the server?

I triple checked if there is an update missing by running the steamcmd update commands multiple times:

```
# ./steamcmd.sh

Steam>login anonymous

Connecting anonymously to Steam Public...Success.

Steam>app_update 90 validate
 Initial App state (0x6) installed
 App state (0x10106) reconfiguring, progress: 0.00 (0 / 0)
 App state (0x506) installed, progress: 0.00 (0 / 0)
Success! App '90' fully installed.

Steam>app_set_config 90 mod dod

Steam>app_update 90 validate
 Initial App state (0x4) installed
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 0.00 (9668 / 391760481)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 27.05 (105956121 / 391760481)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 47.26 (185133333 / 391760481)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 73.23 (286869026 / 391760481)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 94.17 (368931937 / 391760481)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 68.35 (467947887 / 684588459)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 81.53 (558157566 / 684588459)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 95.22 (651894589 / 684588459)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 62.85 (710478159 / 1130520411)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 71.13 (804126816 / 1130520411)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 81.43 (920535890 / 1130520411)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 89.64 (1013365658 / 1130520411)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 94.00 (1062643683 / 1130520411)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 96.27 (1088331848 / 1130520411)
 App state (0x20104) validating, progress: 98.88 (1117911250 / 1130520411)
 Initial App state (0x126) installed
 App state (0x126) installed, progress: 0.00 (0 / 2571936)
 App state (0x300526) downloading, progress: 50.00 (6764735 / 13529283)
Success! App '90' fully installed.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you opened the 27016 port for your IP in your router? Could be that it is blocked, and therefore you cannot connect.

Comment: I also tried the default port (the one the CS server successfully used) and it still does not work. I think it might be an issue with the 1.2 vs 1.3 version but I have no idea how I can update my server when the `app_update 90` say that everything is fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the starting call by adding the map parameter and it works:

```
./hlds_run -console -game dod +maxplayers 8 -port 27016 +map dod_avalanche
```

The output changed:

```
Auto-restarting the server on crash

Console initialized.
Using breakpad crash handler
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 30
Forcing breakpad minidump interfaces to load
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Protocol version 48
Exe version 1.1.2.6/Stdio (dod)
Exe build: 17:45:07 Apr 25 2013 (6027)
STEAM Auth Server
Server IP address 78.47.102.222:27016
scandir failed:/home/hlds/steam/SteamApps/common/Half-Life/./dod/SAVE
[S_API FAIL] SteamAPI_Init() failed; SteamAPI_IsSteamRunning() failed.
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit

couldn't exec listip.cfg
couldn't exec banned.cfg
Connection to Steam servers successful.
   VAC secure mode is activated.
```

The last two lines seem to be the important ones, without that the server seems to not be accessible...